# Shared preferences from an intent

Tags: android

I am trying to get the value of my intent saved with shared preferences but struggling. i cant get any values saved. can somebody advise.

I need to take the value from the indent which is launched from the onActivityResult

I could even accept the CharSequence as a string. I need the intent value saved

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        // The user has selected a place. Extract the name and address.
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);


        LatLng placeLatLng = place.getLatLng(); // gett lat lng from place
        double placeLat = placeLatLng.latitude;
        double placeLong = placeLatLng.longitude;
        final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        final LatLng location = place.getLatLng();
        Marker destination = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(placeLat, placeLong)).title("This is your destination"));

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Current Location
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        //Current Location LatLong
        final double currentLat = myLocation.getLatitude();
        final double currentLng = myLocation.getLongitude();



        //Directions From Current Location To Destination
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + currentLat + "," + currentLng + "&daddr=" + placeLat + "," + placeLong));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        //historyDBHandler.addHistory(history);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}




private String getInfo(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Place Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String mapInfo = sharedPreferences.getString("map Info", "no data recorded");
    return mapInfo;
}
private void saveValues(CharSequence name, CharSequence address){
    Double text = Double.valueOf(new String().toString());
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Place Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("map info", "help" );
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you trying to save a full `Intent` in the shared preferences? Is this the `Intent` you receive in the `onActivityResult`?

Comment: The Intent is the value i need to save, ive tried all sorts of code to put the sharedpref inside the onActivityResult but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

You're putting with the key "map info" but getting with the key "map Info".

Comment: Thats not the question, java is case sensitive. My question is how do i bring the intent data out of the method.